# Can one receive the non-gold version of a Promo Set card from a Hearthstone pack?

Tags: hearthstone

I see conflicting reports on us.battle.net concerning whether or not it is possible to pull the non-golden version of a Promo Card (that is, non-golden Elite Tauren Chieftain or non-golden Gelbin Mekkatorque) from a regular Hearthstone pack.  Some people there say yes, other people say no, and I can't locate an official source.

Can this happen, or is the only way to get these (admittedly awful) cards by crafting them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Official word can be found [here](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/11354925396#7), and two posts below that:

> Golden Gelbin Mekkatorque is acquired by making a purchase with the Hearthstone in-game store. It is currently still available in Open Beta. It is not craftable.
>
> Regular Gelbin Mekkatorque can be crafted using Arcane Dust.
>
> Golden Elite Tauren Chieftain was a part of our BlizzCon In-Game Goodies card, which was acquired by attending BlizzCon 2013 or by purchasing the BlizzCon Virtual Ticket. It is not craftable.
>
> Regular Elite Tauren Chieftain can be crafted using Arcane Dust.

That post dates from 1/21/2014, but as far as I'm aware, there have been no changes since (except for the beta ending, so Golden Mekkatorque is no longer available).

Additionally, neither one can be drafted in the arena, [according to a dev on twitter](https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/491599467435814912).

<sub>Thanks to [this](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=858/gelbin-mekkatorque#comments:id=1894628) and [this](http://www.hearthhead.com/card=1754/elite-tauren-chieftain#comments:id=1925027) for links</sub>